# Can't set Build Action to GoogleServiceJson

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I'm working with Xamarin-Android to make an application, so I need to set Build Action to my google-services.json file but there is no such Property as GoogleServicesJson, and when I try just to write it, it shows me an exception:

> Exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException'
>   was thrown.

I tried to save and then restart Visual Studio, but it didn't solve the problem.

If you know how to solve this problem, please help me! :)
[That's the file I'm clicking on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXfJ7.png)

Comment: I added screenshot to the whole solution, so you can see that I am clicking exactly on the file that is located in Xamarin.Android project. :)

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, but tried to do this in VS 2015, there is no difference

Comment: @SushiHangover I added Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging, thought It is enough. But now when I added Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement it can be set, Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Try right click on file / properties / build actoin / googleservicesjson - fixed it for me.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `GoogleServicesJson` build type comes from the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets`.

If your project does not have `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` installed via one of its dependents, usually `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` or `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` if we are talking about messaging, then you will not have that build action available.

After adding a package that installs Basement, or manually adding it yourself, your `.csproj` will contain an import for `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets` and `GoogleServicesJson` will be available as a build type:

`.csproj` import example:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets')" />
```

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover.  To anyone finding this, remember to update the version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement and the relative path where it can be found in the import directive. Also, if you have more than one Android project in your solution, the path may be to a different project, not your current one, so you may need to do some digging with FileExplorer.

Comment: If you don't see it after installed, just restart Visual Studio.

Comment: It's worth noting that I reference another VStudio project that has this NuGet dependency on Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging but the app project didn't.  It compiles fine relying on the reference project NuGets but Visual Studio doesn't pick it up for the IDE build actions - more info here For me I added a firebase NuGet to ensure the build option appears - as per https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175159/i-didnt-find-googleservices-json-in-the-build-action?

Comment: any specific version i need to use.. i have installed 71.1620.4 but i am not able to find GoogleServiceJson as build option

Comment: Another note: you do only need to install the dependency into the project compiling the resouces (eg android project only) do not install this into xamarin.forms or even ios. this might just interefere with the linker and app size.

Answer (score 26):

Even after installing "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" GoogleServiceJson option was not showing. Surprisingly but when i quit Xamarin studio and opened it again it starts displaying.

Comment: Same for Visual Studio for mac

Comment: I didn't have to close the IDE (Visual Studio for Mac), I only had to close and reopen the solution.

Comment: Same for me! Thank you

Comment: Today I had the same problem with VSMac. I'm also sure that I already restarted once by the way after reading your answer I tried again and it worked, so thank you.

Answer (score 7):

1-Download first these Packages:

```
Xamarin.Firebase.Common

Xamarin.Firebase.Config

Xamarin.Firebase.Iid

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks
```

2-then restart and rebuild
3-from **google-services.json** --> Properties --> build Action: `GoogleServicesJson`

Comment: any specific version i need to use.. i have installed all the packages but i am not able to find GoogleServiceJson as build option..

Comment: All these packages are Android specific - need to install them only in Android project. Once done, rebuild all, close Visual Studio and open again.

Comment: did you try reinstalling your OS while you're at it lol

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio close the Project and reopen it. That worked for me:)

Answer (score 3):

I tried installing every single package that people have suggested installing, I restarted my visual studio after each one, tried running as admin, restarted my computer, NOTHING would work. I could not get the GoogleServicesJson option to show up in my Build Actions list.

Looking at @SushiHangover 's comment, I tried just copying and pasting that line into my .shproj file and changed it to match the path to my nuget packages

```
  <Import Project="C:\Users\<my user>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\117.6.0.3\build\monoandroid90\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Users\<my user>\.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\117.6.0.3\build\monoandroid90\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets')" />
```

And this is the only thing that would finally work for me. Hope that it helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Download first these Packages:

[image]

then restart

[image]

Comment: Please add the package name into the text of your answer.  Also, please change "enter image description here" to a description that is useful.

Answer (score 2):

GoogleServiceJsom is coming from Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement package. If it is not visible after the package installation restart your visual studio project, it will work

Answer (score 0):

I thougt i was doing it wrong but you dont get the Build action by rightklick it like a example from Mac
[image]

**PS You dont right klick on the Google-Services.json and see the Build avtion
You press properties and then at the properties you find the Build action**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While using AppCenter, I was not adding App centre and App Center Push packages to Android Dependencies folder. Upon adding GoogleServicesJson immediately showed up

Answer (score 0):

I was getting stuck with this because the Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows which was saying to install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base directly.

What worked:
install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm through Nuget

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by installing the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement package and restarting Visual Studio.