# Can't set Build Action to GoogleServiceJson After Installing Plugin.FirebasePushNotification

Tags: xamarin

Using visual studio for Mac v8.4.8.

I just installed in my Xamarin project `Plugin.FirebasePushNotification`. Following the steps for Android https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md it says

> Add google-services.json to Android project. Make sure build action is GoogleServicesJson

I added google-services.json to my Android project, but when I try to change the build action, GoogleServicesJson is not listed. Looking online I saw tips to get it to show up by closing the solution or clean all and build. none of these work.

Is there a step missing? Am I supposed to install another plugin?

Comment: restart Visual Studio

Comment: If the `GoogleServicesJson` build action is not shown, save and close the solution, then reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If this issue was solved, can I post my comment to answer?

Comment: restarted twice didnt work yet.. VS 2019 16.7.7 (Windows)

Comment: This answer helped me fix it in my case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42678503/10329199. Install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets

Comment: It's worth noting that I reference another VStudio project that has this NuGet dependency on Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging but the app project didn't.  It compiles fine relying on the reference project NuGets but Visual Studio doesn't pick it up for the IDE build actions - more info here For me I added a firebase NuGet to ensure the build option appears - as per https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175159/i-didnt-find-googleservices-json-in-the-build-action?