# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process FoodAllergyFix.Android. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

```
ava.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process FoodAllergyFix.Android. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12890
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00008] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:151
  at Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/generated/com.google.firebase.firebase-iid/obj/Release/monoandroid12.0/generated/src/Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.cs:163
  at FoodAllergyFix.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0008a] in /Users/satishdurga/Documents/FAF/develop-satish/food-allergy-fix-mobile-application/FoodAllergyFix.Android/MainActivity.cs:124
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00010] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-31/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:2791
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x00005] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:121
  at at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process FoodAllergyFix.Android. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
  at at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:186)
  at at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.1.0:1)
  at at crc64cf8f748391fcc334.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at crc64cf8f748391fcc334.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Hi. I am getting this exception in xamarin.forms in my macbook. i used to use a windows machine to develop and build the android apps. recently i moved to macbook and I am getting this exception while app being deployed into the android emulator. Most of the answers are related androd studio IDE and build.gradle. I can not find the answers related to xamarin projects.

Any one had this exception or solution for this please respond back.
Thank you.
visual studio version:2022 comunity edition, Version 17.5 (build 1802)

Comment: Did you confirm that you downloaded the google-services.json file from the project console, place it in the assets folder, and make sure it has the "GoogleServicesJson" value as Build Action?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Project has a google-service.josn file in xxx.Android root directory. But, I dont see the "GoogleServiceJson" Key in that. However, I have no problem in windows machine(same Project). I can deploy the app in emulator without fail in windows machine. I have only problem with my new macBook.

Answer (score 0):

> Project has a google-service.josn file in xxx.Android root directory.
> But, I dont see the "GoogleServiceJson" Key in that.

The `GoogleServicesJson` build type comes from the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets`.

If your project does not have `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` installed via one of its dependents, usually `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` or `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` which is about messaging, then you will not have that build action available.

After adding a package that installs `Basement`, or manually adding it yourself, your `.csproj` will contain an import for `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets` and `GoogleServicesJson` will be available as a build type:

`.csproj` import example:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.42.1001.0\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets')" />
```

so, you can try the following steps:

1.recheck if you have installed the necessary nuget for your android project:

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement
```

2.Then restart your visual studio and rebuild your app;

Reference:[Can't set Build Action to GoogleServiceJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677766/cant-set-build-action-to-googleservicejson).